# Eclipse and C++ indexer

Tags: c++, eclipse, indexer

I have some problems with Eclipse C++ indexer.

Sometimes it just breaks. Everything is OK in my code and some whole files get tainted of red with unresolved names. I have to rebuild the whole index to make my project well-indexed again.

However on big projects, the indexing can be quite long and this is annoying to rebuild it again and again.

Are there any known fixes for this issue (other than not using Eclipse, I'll save you that one)?
Else, is there an alternative C++ indexer package doing better than Eclipse's built-in one ?